# Reading XML through C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a link which gives a XML data. I want to process the data in my application.

How to handle this in C#?

Through XmlReader or do I need to download the XML data

Which one is the optimum way?

Comment: **System.Linq.Xml** namespace contains good libraries to read and manipulate xmls

Comment: You say that you receive Xml data from some kind of feed. Maybe you can specify that you want JSON instead? JSON is almost the same thing as Xml but I find JSON to much easier/more fun to deal with. Many web services can reply in both Xml and JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the xml document from your link like this

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {            
        string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    }
```

No you can use [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to parse the xmlDoc

```
// Create the query 
var custs = from c in xmlDoc.Elements("Customers") 
          select c ;

// Execute the query 
foreach (var customer in custs) 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine(customer); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `XDocument` because it makes it very simple to then query the xml in a Linq style.
Except if you have very special needs or constraints, it's by far far the most convenient, I think.

Answer (score 0):

first download your data in xml file and then
you can use this code for xml read

```
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("filename.xml"));
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)ds.Tables[0];
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Using the XmlSerializer to deserialize the string you receive back into an object graph:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    T deserialized;
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer= new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings(); //
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            deserialized = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
    return deserialized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See following Image .

[image]

You will need following namespace:
 **System.Xml;**
To see how XPath works , Go here : 
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp